# How can switched outlet work without connected secondary hot wire?

Tags: switch, receptacle

We just moved into a house where I am replacing outlets and switches, and I can't figure this one switched outlet out. I am trying to control the top half of the receptacle with the switch. When the red wire is not connected to the switch (like it is in the attached picture) both parts of the outlet are on. How is it possible? Yet, when I do connect the red wire to the switch, the switch starts controlling not just that particular outlet, but all outlets in the same room and even some one floor down. What am I doing wrong? The hot wire is the one marked with a transparent tape in the picture with the switch.

I know I should have paid attention to how all the wires were connected before I disconnected them, but it is too late now.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: possibly not the two ends of the same red wire

Comment: how do you know both halves of the socket is on?   did you plug an appliance in? those non-contact sensors will see "ghost voltage"s

Comment: 3 blacks and 1 red   Are you putting all 3 blacks together then switching the red? Why is there a loose black?

Comment: @Jasen Yes, I have a ceiling light fixture wired into the top half of the outlet. It is the same half that I am trying to control with a switch.

Comment: @EdBeal One black is loose for testing purposes only. When I put all three blacks together and then switching the red, both halves of the outlet are hot no matter whether the switch is on or off.

Comment: You will need to identify the hot coming into the switch I would expect it to be a black and the switched one red, it could be the red. once you find the hot then you can figure out why both sides are switched possibly a parallel feed to the receptacles, since you have basically connected them all together there is no safety issues (all the wires on the switch turned on is the same as all connected together.)  with out a meter or non contact tester you will have to try the different combinations.